# reachGoal js, в консоли обращение к счетчику идет, в метрике не отображается

Tags: javascript, yandex-metrika-api

Есть некий сайт, на нем стоит метрика, в самой метрике переходы считаются корректно, она "зеленая" и с виду с ней все хорошо. Создал тестовую цель по загрузке страницы. Залил скрипт вида:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    ym(50519953,'reachGoal','load');
}
```

Все работает корректно, есть обращение в консоли, есть переходы в самой цели в ЯМ. Все отлично.
Создал цель с покупкой, добавил в скрипт подтверждения заказа:

```js
$(".buynal").click(function() {
    var cook = $.cookie('sale');
    var phone = $("#uphone").val();
    var comm = $("#ucomm").val();
    var adres = $("#uadress").val();
    var name1 = $("#uname1").val();
    var name2 = $("#uname2").val();
    var mail = $("#umail").val();
    var bon = $(".butbonus").attr('param');
    var coupon_code = $('#cupon').val();

    ym(50519953,'reachGoal','buy2');


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/crm/ajax2.php",
        data: "event=tovars&tovars="+cook+"&name1="+name1+"&name2="+name2+"&mail="+mail+"&adress="+adres+"&city=1&phone="+phone+"&comment="+comm+"&bonus="+bon+"&skidka=0&coupon_code="+coupon_code,
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
            if(html == 0) {
                alert('Ошибка');
            } else {
                $.cookie('sale', '', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
                $('#ModalCart').arcticmodal({
                    closeOnEsc: false,
                    closeOnOverlayClick: false
                });

            }
        }
    });
})
```

В консоли все вроде-бы хорошо, обращение есть :

```
PageView. Counter  50519953 . URL:  https://****.ru/cart.php . Referrer: https://****.ru/?_ym_debug=1 . Params:  undefined
tag.js:579 Params. Counter 50519953. Params:  {roistat-visit-id: "104851"}
about:blank:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
cart.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
tag.js:579 Reach goal. Counter: 50519953. Goal id: buy2. Params:  undefined
cart.php:263 558
Navigated to https://****.ru/client.php?p=2
```

...третья с конца строчка. Params по-умолчанию не передаются. В цели которая была по загрузке страницы, было также, но она работала корректно....если что, не пинайте ногами, с js, а тем более с метрикой сталкиваюсь крайне редко.

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил, сам ответил))...по первой цели просто учлись НЕ МОИ переходы. По второй, переходы не учлись, так как событие более редкое и на тот момент были только мои, а на счетчике стояла галка их не учитывать, про которую я не знал. Технически то все крайне просто, и где-то очень глубоко зарытых камней, которые я искал часов 5 не оказалось)